# Notation for Propability Amplitudes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, probability, amplituhedron

I've recently stumbled upon a certain piece of notation that doesn't quite seem clear to me. When discussing the [amplituhedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplituhedron), my teacher mentioned the relation between the volume and the amplitude scattering, and then he wrote the following on the board:
$$[1-,\,1+,\,3-,\,3+]$$
I assume these are probability amplitudes, but I don't quite what the integers and the signs mean.

Comment: I know nothing about amplituhedra, so this may be entirely wrong:  sometimes the notation 1+ is used to denote a real number that is indefinitely close to 1.  as in lim (x-->O+) to mean the limit as x approaches zero from the right.

Comment: I would hope the instructor didn't just write that down in vacuo - was there some additional context?

Comment: FWIW, the $\pm$ are helicities of a 4-particle amplitude.

Comment: You know, I have had this on the back of my mind for four years; never quite returned to it. Now, it made sense haha. Thanks!